# S3 methods with no default and separate arguments

Tags: r, roxygen2

I wanted to see what is a good praxis for implementing S3 methods with no `default`.
Suppose we have two classes that function `f` takes, class `a` and class `b`, and these are the only inputs the function `f` can take.
In addition, suppose both classes have different additional arguments.

We define:

```
f <- function(x, common_par, other_par1, other_par2) {
    UseMethod("f")
}

f.a <- function(x, common_par, other_par1) {
    print(x, common_par, other_par1) # Hey no need to be complicated; clearly these would be more complex
}

f.b <- function(x, common_par, other_par2) {
    print(x, common_par, other_par2) # Hey no need to be complicated; clearly these would be more complex
}
```

What are the best ways to add `Roxygen2` annotation to these type of situations?

Comment: You can do like the `?predict` function does. Just document the generic function with `function(x, ...)` And then make separate documentation for your implementation methods like `?predict.lm` so you only document the relevant parameters for the specific classes involved.

Comment: @MrFlick Ok. Then, do I just put something like `stopifnot(...)` inside the generic function? Also to clarify, by generic, do you mean `f.default`? Also, can I ignore the warnings I get regarding inconsistent S3 method I get the following: `checking S3 generic/method consistency` followed by  `estimate_beta:
     function(reg, mean, alpha, m, s)
   estimate_beta.glm:
     function(reg, mean, alpha)` where `estimate_beta` just contains `UseMethod(...)`.

Comment: By the generic I mean `f` itself. You don't necessarily need a .default. If you don't provide one R will return an error something like "no applicable method for 'f' applied to an object of class ...". You would only need to provide your own if you want to change the error message to something else.

Comment: @MrFlick Ok, and the warnings regarding inconsistency in the S3 function parameters can be ignored? (trying to get this on CRAN once completed).

Comment: What do the warnings say exactly? if `estimate_beta` has `function(reg, mean, alpha, m, s) ` but `estimate_beta.glm` just has `function(reg, mean, alpha)` then that's wrong. The version without the `.` should not have any parameters not included in all implementations. `estimate_beta` should just be `function(reg, ...)` with the literal ellipsis.

Comment: The declarations currently listed in the question won't work.  The declarations for the methods need to be compatible with the declaration for the generic.  Follow @MrFlick's recommendation, and change the generic -- but also change the methods to add `...`.  You can confirm that it's empty at runtime.

Comment: And Roxygen2 is irrelevant.  It just writes .Rd files.  It will write them to follow what the code says, so get the code right.